# Wronskian Differential Equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

$3y''+(6/x)y'+3e^xy = 0$ and two $y_1$, $y_2$ are two partial solutions of such that $W(y_1, y_2) \ne 0$.

(where $W(y_1, y_2) = W(x)$ is the Wronskian of $y_1$, $y_2$). If it is known that $W(1) = 2$, calculate $W(10)$.
I know that i have to find a function first but i do not know how. Also i can check if they are linearly independent but how can i calculate $W(10)$.  I can not find any solved examples. Please help.

Comment: What is meant here by $y_1, y_2$ being "partial" solutions? Do you just mean solutions? Also, would you mind rewriting the equation in MathJax to avoid any ambiguity in the notation? You very likely don't actually need to know the functions themselves. (see [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity))

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We dont need to solve the DE we just need to create a function of x (which we dont know yet.) using (1) -> W(x)=y1y2'-y2y1'                                         
(2) ->y1''+(2/x)y1'+e^xy1=0 and (3)-> y2''+(2/x)y2'+e^xy=0 So using (1),(2),(3) we need to create a new DE and plug in W(1)=2 .Then we can find W(10) But how can we do that? How we can combine (1)(2)(3) and create another DE. P.S. I dont know how to use MathJax but i will search it right now.

Comment: The process for creating a new ODE for the Wronskian is detailed in the link from my earlier comment. (under the Proof section) Do you understand the process shown there?

Comment: I am afraid no.The exact same process is  also described in my differential equation book but without any step by step  examples.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me what part of the proof you have difficulty with, so I might help you understand it? Sorry to say it but in this case I don't think working out a given example step by step is actually any easier than talking about the general case

Comment: The whole proccess actually really makes me confused. I can understand everything until W'=-pW (which is a first order DE) So in my problem it would look like this w'=-2/xw . Now if i integrate both sides i end up with lnw=-2lnx so w=1/x^2. If i plug W(1) -> W=1/1 -> W=1 and not 2 {W(1)=2}

Comment: Ah alright. Well in that case your issue is that you've forgotten your constant of integration when you integrate, you should get $\ln |W| = -2 \ln|x| + C,$ so after a little manipulation we have $W = \frac{C}{x^2}.$ Now you can solve for $C$ using your condition for $W.$

Comment: But still how can we put x=1 and get W=2 that means that c must be equal to 2 am i right? (The original question says that if it is know that W(1)=2 then calculate W(10) so we just take for granted that c is equal to 2? But if thats true how can we calculate W(10) then?

Comment: $W(1) = C = 2,$ so we have $W(x) = \frac2{x^2}.$ So what do we get when we plug in $x = 10$?

Comment: So W(10)=2/100 and thats it? so the function that we were looking for was found by intergrating 1/w and -2/x . The proof that we used for this particular problem can be used and for other similar problems or this one had something that made us think of Abels theorem?

Comment: The method we used here should be applicable for any second order linear ODE, since that's the form of equations that Abel's identity works for.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is defined as

$W(y_1, y_2) = \det \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2' \end{bmatrix} = y_1y_2' - y_2 y_1'; \tag 1$

we may easily find the derivative

$W' = y_1'y_2' + y_1y_2'' - y_2'y_1' - y_2y_1'' = y_1y_2'' - y_2y_1''; \tag 2$

further progress is made using the given equation

$3y''+(6/x)y'+3e^xy = 0, \tag 3$

out of which the constant factor $3$ may be divided, leaving

$y'' + (2/x)y'+ e^xy = 0, \tag 4$

which we know $y_1$ and $y_2$ solve; thus we have

$W'$
$= y_1(-((2/x)y_2' + e^xy_2)) - y_2(-((2/x)y_1' + e^xy_1)) = -(2/x)y_1y_2' - e^xy_1y_2 + (2/x)y_2y_1' + e^xy_1y_2$
$= -(2/x)y_1y_2'+ (2/x)y_2y_1' = -(2/x)(y_1y_2' - y_2y_1') =-(2/x)W; \tag 5$

once the clutter of this equation is removed we are left with

$W' = -(2/x)W, \tag 6$

which is a case of [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity); the unique solution to (6) taking the value $W(1)$ at $1$ is

$W(x) = W(1)\exp \left (-\displaystyle \int_1^x (2/s)\;ds \right); \tag 7$

we may easily evaluate the integral:

$\displaystyle \int_1^x (2/s)\;ds = 2\int_1^x (1/s)\;ds = 2(\ln x - \ln 1) = 2\ln x = \ln x^2; \tag 8$

thus,

$W(x) = W(1)\exp(-\ln x^2) = W(1)\exp(\ln x^{-2}) = W(1)x^{-2}.   \tag 9$

Now with

$W(1) = 2, \; x = 10, \tag{10}$

$W(x) = 2(10)^{-2} = 2(.01) = .02. \tag{11}$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @PaulK.:  my pleasure, my friend! ***Cheers!!!***